# iphone simulator runs cached copy of app-in-development

Tags: iphone

I've been making changes to my app, but they don't appear when I attempt to build and run using the debugger.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a way to delete the old copy of the binary?

I have source control (SVN) set up; could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XCode, make sure that your app isn't running in the simulator (click the red stop-button), then click the Build menu -> Clean target (or just do SHIFT-CMD-K), and try to run it again.
XCode may be using a precompiled version of the app.